# How do I return columns in timeseries data as arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I am using postgres and timescaledb to record data that will be used for dashboards/charting.

I have no issues getting the data I need I'm just not sure if I'm doing it the most efficient way.

Say I have this query

```
   SELECT time, queued_calls, active_calls 
   FROM call_data  ​
   ​ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

My front end receives this data for charting like such.
[image]

I feel like this is very inefficient by repeating the column name for each value.

Would it be better to send the data in a more efficient way like each column as an array of data like such.

```
{
time: [...], 
queued_calls: [...], 
active_calls: [...]
}
```

I guess my question is, should I be restructuring my query so the column data is in arrays somehow or is this something I should be doing after the query on the server before sending it to the client?

-- Update -- Additional Information

I'm using Node.js with Express and Sequelize as the ORM, however in this case I'm just executing a raw query via Sequelize.

The charting library I'm using on the front end also takes the series data as arrays so I was trying to kill two birds with one stone.

Frontend chart data format:

```
xaxis:{
  categories: [...time]
}
series:[
   {name: "Queued Calls", data: [...queued_calls]},
   {name: "Active Calls", data: [...active_calls]}
]
```

Backend code:

```
async function getLocationData(locationId) {
  return await db.sequelize.query(
    'SELECT time, queued_calls, active_calls FROM location_data WHERE location_id = :locationId ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 100;',
    {
      replacements: { locationId },
      type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    }
  );
}

...

app.get('/locationData/:locationId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { locationId } = req.params;
    const results = await getLocationData(parseInt(locationId));
    res.send(results);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error getting data', e);
  }
});
```

Comment: What tool are you using that converts the values into JSON?  Interfaces to databases do not typically automatically transform results into JSON for transport.  The data is highly structured, so the internal format should be sending the header followed by the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the response I've added additional details to the original post. My front end code also uses the data in a way that I would end up having to manipulate the data to get it in the array form anyways. So I was hoping to just send it already in the desired structure. I just wasn't sure if I should be: 1) trying to get the SQL query to return desired structure initially. 2) write a function to transform the data after the query but before I send to the client. 3) write a function client side to structure the data before plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for array aggregation?

Let me see if I follow the idea:

```sql
create table call_data (time timestamp, queued_calls integer, active_calls integer);
CREATE TABLE
```

I skipped the location_id just to simplify here.

Inserting some data:

```sql
tsdb=> insert into call_data values ('2021-03-03 01:00', 10, 20);
INSERT 0 1
tsdb=> insert into call_data values ('2021-03-03 02:00', 11, 22);
INSERT 0 1
tsdb=> insert into call_data values ('2021-03-03 03:00', 12, 25);
INSERT 0 1
```

And now check the data:

```sql
SELECT time, queued_calls, active_calls FROM call_data;
        time         | queued_calls | active_calls
---------------------+--------------+--------------
 2021-03-03 01:00:00 |           10 |           20
 2021-03-03 02:00:00 |           11 |           22
 2021-03-03 03:00:00 |           12 |           25
(3 rows)
```

And if you want to get only the dates you'll have:

```sql
 SELECT time::date, queued_calls, active_calls FROM call_data;
    time    | queued_calls | active_calls
------------+--------------+--------------
 2021-03-03 |           10 |           20
 2021-03-03 |           11 |           22
 2021-03-03 |           12 |           25
(3 rows)
```

but still not grouping, so, you can use group by combined with [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) for it:

```sql
SELECT time::date, array_agg(queued_calls), array_agg(active_calls) FROM call_data group by time::date;
    time    | array_agg  | array_agg
------------+------------+------------
 2021-03-03 | {10,11,12} | {20,22,25}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the server is compressing data as it sends it won't make much difference over the network layer if you send the data in the array structure you're thinking of.

If you use the array structure you're thinking of you're breaking one of the benefits of JSON - structure with data. You might gain some speed increase but if you want to see the active calls for a time you'd have to have the correct index - and open the possibilty of index errors.

I recommend leaving the data as it is.

Comment: You may gain some speed in data transmission time. But would any speed gained packing the data be lost in additional processing to match array elements? I guess that would depend on the processing language/code.  Further as @GordonLinoff indicates Postgres is not transmitting that (the query would have to specify some JSON to do so).  Some layer in your stack is doing it.

Comment: The speed increase is marginal once you get to processing the elements in javascript.

Comment: Agreed, but the time saved in data transmission is also marginal.  Likely to be a tradeoff.

Comment: But it would be interesting to see time tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's guys, I've added a bit more info to the main post and also under  Gordon Linoff question on the original post. Sounds like I wouldn't get a ton of benefit network wise however let me add a new question. If my front end also uses the data in the array type format I'm asking about, would it change your recommendation on sending it as is? Or should I try and structure it before I send it? If so should I do it via a function after the query or is there some SQL to get it to my desired format?

Comment: @HexxNine I'd change it in the middle tier - as you're using node the function could be moved to the front end if need be without much hassle.